# Where is the Xservers file on Debian 8?

Tags: linux, debian, x-server

Can't seem to find the Xservers file. The `locate` command does not find it, and I have checked in `/etc/kde4/kdm` it is not there either.

I looked in `/etc/X11` and the only directories present in `/etc/X11` are: `/app_defaults`, `/cursors`, `/fonts`, `/xkb`, `/xinit`, `/Xreset.d`, `/Xresoources`, `/Xsession.d`, and `/xsm`.

Is it deprecated? If yes where can I find info on this? I have tried looking all around Google to no avail.

Comment: `whereis X` should tell you: `X: /usr/bin/X /usr/share/man/man7/X.7.gz`... `kdm` is NOT a Xserver.

Comment: @cylgalad Thak you for your input, I am well aware that kdm is not an Xserver. I am not looking for the Xserver itself, I am rather looking for a configuration file called "Xserver**s**" (note the "s" at the end)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Xservers` file is part of XDM, so you should install the package first. The [file](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/xdm/filelist) will then be available in `/etc/X11/xdm/`.

Comment: Awesome, that was exactly what i was looking for, plus i have just learned that i can search through all packages via the link you provided to see which package "bundles" the files I am looking for and where to find them once the package is installed. Thanks alot

Comment: Quick question though, do you know if it would be possible to do the same search on a terminal via `apt` (a.k.a, search for a filename and have `apt` return the "parent" package name)?

Comment: NVM. I got it, it can be done via the `apt-file search` command. Thanks for your input